# Can you have BOTH Custom Error Pages and Scripting Errors Sent to Browser IIS 7 Server

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7, custom-error-pages

Hoping to have the best of both worlds... Need scripting errors (500 errors) sent to browser window so we can debug items as we go... but was also hoping to have a custom 404 page (page not found).  I am NOT using a config file because have direct access in the IIS server panel.

When you turn on the scripting errors it does great, but it shows the "nasty root error htm file" for the 404 (page not found).  Tried changing the error page directory in the IIS > Error Pages > 404 but it won't redirect to custom page because it is sending the errors to browser.  Again, was hoping for both - 500 show errors, 404 show custom page.  Ideas...?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...

1. IIS > ASP > Debugging Properties > Send Errors to Browser (already had done)
2. IIS > Error Pages > Edit Feature Settings > populated below:  (was blank) >

Default Page -
Path: /500.asp
Path type: Execute URL

Allows the 404 error redirect but 500-script/database errors get redirected to this page.

Took forever to find the solution - thanks to davidtg at forums.iis.net